# Create a category using multiple columns in AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics, amazon-quicksight

I'm using AWS QuickSight for analytics. I have two columns in my CSV file that shows a doctor's specialty. Specialty1 and Specialty2. Now I want to show Specialty1 and Specialty2 on the x-axis. How Can I achieve it?

Use case example: I want to know how many doctor have a specific Specialty. It could be their first specialty or their second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **30 May 2022**

Here is AWS support answer to this issue:

> Currently in QuickSight you can insert two fields in to the x axis , however this converts the visual into a hierarchy format where only one field is represented in the visual at a time.
> I'm sorry QuickSight doesn't currently behave in the way you are expecting. However I can see how this functionality could be useful. Therefore I have created a feature request on your behalf to  enable a feature to allow for multiple fields to be used in the  x-axis’s in a bar chart to be used simultaneously in a single visual.
> However, due to the varying workloads and priorities of the team, I can't say when or if this functionality will be made available. To keep abreast with all the latest developments in QuickSight though, you can keep an eye on the following links, as this is where any new features will be announced:
> - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/quicksight/latest/user/WhatsNew.html
> - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/?awsf.blog-master-analytics-products=category-analytics%23amazon-quicksight